# Schedule net user command using at in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

In Windows 7 I am trying to schedule the following command to run:

```
net user testuser /active:no
```

Then I type the following at the prompt

```
at 4:20 "net user testuser /active:no"
```

After which I see my job scheduled and the command looks correct. Yet after the time has passed the user's status is still active so I run the following fromt he command line:

```
net user testuser /active:no
```

Now everything works as desired. How do I get AT to run my `net user` command?

Comment: checked the system event log to see what happened at 4:20?

Comment: Yeah, thought the same thing. Checked and it didn't show anything.